# Why Does my #DIV stop receiving the Function Clicks once the DIVS are recreated?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function

I have a bunch of divs: #grandparent, #parent, #child. When #child is clicked: the div #books is emptied and the div #book is appended with div #new. When #book is clicked: #book is emptied and the div #books is appended again with new divs #grandparent, #parent, #child.

The problem is once recreated... #child (and probably #book) no longer receives the click function to repeat the process!!
Why is that? How can I get it to just keep repeating? That BOTH #child and #book continue to run the functions. Thanks

```css
body, div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
      left: 50px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
}

.grandparent {
    width: 200px;
    Height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10 and IE 11 */
  user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
  
    cursor: pointer;

}

.parent {
    width: 130px;
    Height: 130px;
    background-color: blue;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10 and IE 11 */
  user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
  
    cursor: pointer;
}

.child {
    width: 60px;
    Height: 60px;
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10 and IE 11 */
  user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
  
    cursor: pointer;
}

.new {
    width: 200px;
    Height: 200px;
    background-color: purple;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10 and IE 11 */
  user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
  
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Touchy!</title>
    
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    
</head>


<body>

<br>
<br>


<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="books" class="books" >
        <div id="grandparent" class="grandparent">
            <div id="parent" class="parent">
                <div id="child" class="child" >07</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
        <div id="book" class="book" ></div>
    
</div>



</body>


<script>


$(document).ready(function() {


const child = document.querySelector(".child")

child.addEventListener("click", e => {
    console.log("child")
})

document.addEventListener("click", e => {
    console.log("document")
})




$( "#child" ).click(function() {

    $("#books").html('');
    $("#book").append("<div id='new' class='new'>12</div>");
    
    console.log("child clicked");

});




$( "#book" ).click(function() {

    $("#book").html('');
    $("#books").append("<div id='grandparent' class='grandparent'>");
    $("#grandparent").append("<div id='parent' class='parent'>");
    $("#parent").append("<div id='child' class='child'>07</div>");
    
    console.log("new clicked");

});


});


</script>



</html>
```

Comment: *Why does my #DIV stop receiving events* - because your #div stops existing.  You then create a *new* #div, which is not the same one (as the old one was deleted and a new one created) so any events for it don't apply, *as it's not the same #div*.   `$("#id").click` only applies to elements that exist at the time the call is made.  Use `$(document).on("click", "#id", function...` for event delegation.

Comment: Thank you -freedom-m  At first I didn’t understand how to correct it lol. But I then changed the click function as you suggested and my page now works and I was able to get it working also within my actual project as well. Thank you. 